# Up-to-date table with iOS emoji characters

Tags: ios, unicode, emoji

I'm trying to find some way to lookup characters like this one online:  (which looks like this on my computer: [image])
This character is `\udbb8\udf35` or `1041205` in decimal and should represent this emoji:

[image]

But lookup tables [like this one](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) shows another character for emoji. As I understand it iOS has changed the emoji unicode codes in the latest versions. Is there an up-to-date table?

Comment: On your Mac, in just about any application, go to the Edit menu and select "Special Characters...".

Comment: @rmaddy and then what? How do I locate the character that I cannot see?

Comment: That seems to be the U+1F60A character ()